# Sequelize: Use query results as table for selectQuery

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is it possible to use the results of a query as a table for another select in sequelize's query generator? Here's the SQL I'm trying to get generated:

```
UPDATE target 
SET fk1_id = '1' 
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM target
        WHERE fk1_id = 1 AND fk2_id = 2
         ) AS inner_target )
    AND fk1_id IS NULL AND fk2_id = '2' LIMIT 1
```

and I'm trying to accomplish this with:

```
const innerSelect = 
sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('target', {
            attributes: ['fk1_id'],
            where: {
                fk1_id: fk1_id,
                fk2_id: fk2_id,
            },
        }).slice(0, -1);

const selectAs = sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(
    sequelize.literal(`${innerSelect}`), {
            attributes: ['id'],
        }).slice(0, -1);
```

however, I get an error saying:

```
"message": "Table 'db.undefined' doesn't exist"
"name": "SequelizeDatabaseError"
"code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE"
```

and the inner select is trying to select from `undefined`

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to that error, you have not created the table you are querying.

Comment: right, but what I would like to do is use the results of the first query ('inner_select') as that "table"

Comment: i think you should just pass your raw SQL query into sequelize.query() function.

Comment: e.g

sequelize.query("Your SQL Query").spread(function (results, metadata) {
/*
 Do something
*/
});